# Reshape the row's organization in a dataframe with R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have this dataframe.

```
structure(list(Driver = c("Crop agriculture", "Infrastructure", 
"Mining", "Mixed Agriculture", "Other land use", "Pasture", "Tree crops", 
"Water", "Crop agriculture", "Infrastructure", "Mining", "Mixed Agriculture", 
"Other land use", "Pasture", "Tree crops", "Water", "Crop agriculture", 
"Infrastructure", "Mining", "Mixed Agriculture", "Other land use", 
"Pasture", "Tree crops", "Water", "Crop agriculture", "Infrastructure", 
"Mining", "Mixed Agriculture", "Other land use", "Pasture", "Tree crops", 
"Water"), Period = c("1990-2000", "1990-2000", "1990-2000", "1990-2000", 
"1990-2000", "1990-2000", "1990-2000", "1990-2000", "1990-2000", 
"1990-2000", "1990-2000", "1990-2000", "1990-2000", "1990-2000", 
"1990-2000", "1990-2000", "2000-2005", "2000-2005", "2000-2005", 
"2000-2005", "2000-2005", "2000-2005", "2000-2005", "2000-2005", 
"2000-2005", "2000-2005", "2000-2005", "2000-2005", "2000-2005", 
"2000-2005", "2000-2005", "2000-2005"), Value = c(129536.358373574, 
14089.3660954917, 985.646531415156, 34951.5705930615, 75478.7796771996, 
1001024.77681633, 9673.51414314377, 51631.4446491193, 0.0983294102032751, 
0.0106950594852475, 0.000748191807457263, 0.0265312948831128, 
0.057294986378404, 0.759865238911138, 0.0073430421561273, 0.0391927761752383, 
273356.204972389, 12040.5899468613, 607.505228212054, 45165.8223684273, 
75748.9976185639, 1221137.74328547, 8851.85933777376, 39629.016246337, 
0.163048047540391, 0.00718181861746466, 0.000362357025480948, 
0.0269399377763239, 0.0451818028644936, 0.728368777437064, 0.00527984496372407, 
0.0236374137750571), n = c("n = 1669", "n = 298", "n = 20", "n = 1355", 
"n = 1623", "n = 10986", "n = 316", "n = 466", "n = 1669", "n = 298", 
"n = 20", "n = 1355", "n = 1623", "n = 10986", "n = 316", "n = 466", 
"n = 783", "n = 151", "n = 7", "n = 925", "n = 851", "n = 6039", 
"n = 211", "n = 244", "n = 783", "n = 151", "n = 7", "n = 925", 
"n = 851", "n = 6039", "n = 211", "n = 244"), Type = c("Sum", 
"Sum", "Sum", "Sum", "Sum", "Sum", "Sum", "Sum", "Percentage", 
"Percentage", "Percentage", "Percentage", "Percentage", "Percentage", 
"Percentage", "Percentage", "Sum", "Sum", "Sum", "Sum", "Sum", 
"Sum", "Sum", "Sum", "Percentage", "Percentage", "Percentage", 
"Percentage", "Percentage", "Percentage", "Percentage", "Percentage"
)), .Names = c("Driver", "Period", "Value", "n", "Type"), row.names = c("1", 
"3", "5", "7", "9", "11", "13", "15", "12", "31", "51", "71", 
"91", "111", "131", "151", "2", "4", "6", "8", "10", "122", "14", 
"16", "21", "41", "61", "81", "101", "121", "141", "161"), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to reorganize this dataframe according to two conditions. First, I want to have in the first 8 rows the `Sum` objects and then the percentages. Then, I also want to couple the same driver classes together. In short, I want to have, for instance, `Crop agriculture` for the period 1990-2000 and right after `Crop agriculture` for the period 2000-2005 and so on. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should provide the desired output for your sample input. Additionally you should provide any code you have written to attempt to accomplish this and clearly describe where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Isn't this just `order`  `C_Em_df[with(C_Em_df, order(Type, Driver)),]`

Comment: The `ddply` function works well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer

```
C_Em_df<-ddply(C_Em_df, .(Type, Driver))
```